# How To Make a Window in Python without GUI toolkits

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm curious, as making a window with Tkinter really does seem to easy. Does Python have an alert thing similar to javascript by default?

Comment: No, it doesn't have GUI by default.

Comment: *does* seem too easy, or *doesn't* seem too easy?  If it seems easy, why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no graphical alert in python. Tkinter is the default python GUI interface. If all you need is an alert, that's less than a dozen lines of code. Here's a python 3 example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

def alert(message):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Alert", message)
    root.destroy()

alert("Danger Will Robinson!")
```